# MlflowException: API request to ...URL... failed to return code 200 after 3 tries

Tags: azure-databricks, mlflow, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently trying to track my machine learning model metrics using the MLFlow API in Azure Databricks.

I registered the experiment under my team's machine learning workspace and had tried a few metric log commands that worked but were simply used as a test.

My notebook ran a for loop logging metrics per calculation within the loop.
It took a while (3-5 seconds) before sending out the error.

I tried to look at the experiment metrics and it seems to have logged a bit of the for loop's metrics before crashing.

Not sure as to why it does it and now it throws the exception to my earlier test calls to log metrics.